# Set and Load table data with cookie

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn about cookies here, but I can't seem to figure them out with tables.

I want to save the data I have in a table and then be able to load the table back with that same data.

At the moment, my code should save the data and then the alert should have the data that has been saved but it isn't working. 
Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

PS. I am trying to do it with old school javascript and not jquery.

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID number</th>
      <th>Assignment 1</th>
      <th>Assignment 2</th>
      <th>Assignment 3</th>
      <th>Assignment 4</th>
      <th>Assignment 5</th>
      <th>Final Average Grade</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">Tom Malarkey</td>
      <td id="left">95243654</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">-</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="button" onclick=calculateAvg()>
    Submit
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="saveTable()">
    Save
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="LoadTable()">
    Load
  </button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> script.js

```
function calculateAvg() {
  var k = document.getElementById("myTable");

  for (var i = 1; i < k.rows.length; i++) {
    var sumOfGrades = 0;

    for (var j = 2; j < k.rows[0].cells.length - 1; j++) {
      if (k.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML != "-") {
        sumOfGrades += parseInt(k.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
      }
    }
    var avg = k.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = Math.round(sumOfGrades / 5);
    k.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = Math.round(avg) + "%";

    if (avg <= 40) {
      k.rows[i].cells[j].style.background = "red";
      k.rows[i].cells[j].style.color = "white";
    } else {
      k.rows[i].cells[j].style.background = "white";
      k.rows[i].cells[j].style.color = "black";
    }
  }
}

function saveTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var num = table.rows[0].cells.length; // amount of rows
  var data = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[0].cells.length - 1; j++) {
      data += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ";";
    }
  }
  data = table.rows.length + ";" + table.rows[0].cells.length + ";" + data.substring(0, data.length);
  setCookie("data", data, 60);
  alert("Cookie Saved");
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {

  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function LoadTable() {
  var data = getCookie("data");
  if (data != "") {
    alert("The table says:" + data);
  } else {
    alert("There is no data in the table");
  }
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

When I currently click on the Load button, it says "The table says:2"

Answer (score 1):

On this line in your `saveTable` function, you overwrite the value set in `data`

```
data = table.rows.length + ";" + table.rows[0].cells.length + ";" + data.substring(0, data.length);
```

You need to *add* value with `+=`

```
data += table.rows.length + ";" + table.rows[0].cells.length + ";" + data.substring(0, data.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It now alerts me with the data in the first cell. I need the data in all of the cells. Any advice?

Comment: you are adding data by ; separated in inner for loop, change the ; to ~ sign

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Thanks for this. I see it working now. One more question.. It still has a 2 at the end. Could you tell me why? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jessie The number `2` comes from the fact that also the first row containing the header is included. Change to this `data += (table.rows.length-1) + ";" ....`

Comment: @Jessie that is nothing but your row count, see line number 86 on fiddle

Comment: Oh! sorry my bad. Thanks a mill for your help!