# Issue with saving table data to a cookie and retrieve that table and its data

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to save the table data to a cookie and access it again at a later date. My question is very similar to 
[Set and Load table data with cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272944/set-and-load-table-data-with-cookie) but it does not answer my problem (I have tried this solution but it didnt work). This is from an old college assignment but I am working on a personal project now but its very similar in regards to the cookie. My code is well commented  at the cookie functions but if more information is needed let me know! thanks in advance

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/16398101/cq3ob458/

```
function setCookie() {
//using ~ to seperate values as , and ; are doing weird things to cookies (explained better below)
  document.cookie += '~ expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT'; // trying to reset cookie each time we enter this function as table could be saved multiple times per session

  var d = new Date(); //get date
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // about 2 months in future
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  var table = document.getElementById("mytab");

  var r = table.rows.length;

  var c = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  var s1 = r + "~" + c + "~"; // get len of rows and cols to add them later
  /* using "~" as "," or ";" made the splitting act weird
                              e.g would add entire cookie into first cell of table*/
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      s1 += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + "~"; //get data from table
    }
  }
  s1 += expires; //add expiration date
  document.cookie = s1;
  console.log("logging s1 " + s1); //cookie looks good until here

}



function getCookie() {
  console.log("In GetCookie");
  var table = document.getElementById("mytab");
  var x = document.cookie;
  console.log("logging x" + x);

  var x1 = x.split("~");

  var r = x1[0];
  var c = x1[1];

  for (var i = 0; i < (r - 2); i++) { // add rows (-2 as already two rows)
    addRow();
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < (c - 4); j++) { // add rows (-4 as already four cols)
    addCol();
  }

  /*   if (x1[0].indexOf("~") > -1) {
      x1[0] = "Student Name";
    }
     */
  var count = 0;
  for (var p = 1; p < table.rows.length; p++) { // row 0 is header therefore ignore
    for (var o = 0; o < table.rows[i].cells.length; o++) { //cols start at 0

      table.rows[p].cells[o].innerHTML = x1[count + 2]; // +2 as 0 and 1 are rows and cols len

      console.log("logging x1[count]" + x1[count]);
      count++;
      add();
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried several different solutions from here and other sites but none seem to work

I expect the table to be restored to the state it was in when it was saved but at the moment it fills the table with "undefined" or noting or the entire cookie in the first cell e.t.c (several results from several different failed solutions)

Note: the code is written in vanilla js but jQuery or any other solution is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to send the table contents to your server? If not, consider using localStorage instead of cookies - it's easier to pick up values from localStorage when you need them.

Also, you could just store/restore the entire innerHTML of the table node instead of building up your own string representation of the table's contents. Example:

```
localStorage.table = document.querySelector('#mytab').innerHTML.trim() // store

document.querySelector('#mytab').innerHTML = localStorage.table // restore
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! I have another question though, is there an expiry on the local storage? and every time I save the table is it overwritten or is a new instance of it saved? Thanks again for the help I was trying for ages and I can't believe there's such a simple solution!

Comment: There's no expiry on localStorage, but there is a limit to how much data you can store (about 5MB, last I checked). And yes, each time you store, you are overwriting what was stored earlier. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea for you:

I'm guessing your data is in Object form, if that's the case, simply use `JSON.stringify(table);`. It will return a string version of your object, and then you can store it as a cookie using `document.cookie()` or using `window.localStorage()` (which I prefer). And when you retrieve it, it'll be in string format, so to switch it back to an object, simply use `JSON.parse(objString)`.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I am doing it right, I tried to log the values both ways but it just logs an empty array?